# Xcode Simulator and Magic Trackpad

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, trackpad

I just would like to know whether Xcode Simulator enable Force Touch functionality, adding the new Apple Magic Trackpad 2 to an iMac (my mac is a middle 2011 model). I need to simulate this feature, saving the money to buy a new MacBook that has it embedded.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Magic Trackpads can be used to send force levels to iOS want watchOS simulator devices.